# What is the best way to create a java.util.Enumeration out of a java stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

My best solution is currently:

```
Collections.enumeration(stream.collect(Collectors.toList()))
```

Hoping for a more concise method than this.

Comment: More _concise_?  Not likely.  _Maybe_ more efficient.

Comment: Just static import enumaration and toList and it becomes `enumeration(stream.collect(toList()))`  You can also use joo-lambda Seq instead of Stream and it becomes `enumeration(seq.toList())`; although, shmosel's answer seems specially made for this use case

Comment: Is there any chance you don't really need Enumeration? It is quite old type which even in its documentation states that "*New implementations should consider using `Iterator` in preference to `Enumeration`*". Maybe this is yet another case of [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Agreed, it would help to give some context. Without any further information, your line of code seems to make a reasonable use of the JDK streams and collections APIs with respect to clarity and readability. The question is what do you _really_ want to achieve?

Comment: Context: I am creating a ResourceBundle with Enums as keys. ResourceBundle requires a Enumeration to be returned. I ended up just creating a new anonymous Enumeration class as it is efficient but its not a one liner.

Answer (score 7):

You can use Guava's [`Iterators.asEnumeration()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#asEnumeration-java.util.Iterator-):

```
Iterators.asEnumeration(stream.iterator())
```

Answer (score 4):

There is also an apache commons based solution [IteratorUtils.asEnumeration](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/IteratorUtils.html#asEnumeration(java.util.Iterator))

```
IteratorUtils.asEnumeration(stream.iterator());
```